# Azure deployment - skip folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, msbuild

I've setup a blog under http://www.mywebsite.com/blog, which is not managed from source control (and I don't wish to manage it from source control, as it it managed by an end-user).

Each time deployment is kicked-off via a bitbucket commit - this folder is deleted as part of the build process. Is there a way I can either get azure or the build process to not delete this folder? (like app_data is persisted?)

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution, for anyone else:

In Azure, yo can setup a virtual folder for your website - and run it alongside wwwroot - put your blog n there, and it will be unaffected.